# Solving the Lippmann-Schwinger equation

Tags: integral-equations

I am trying to solve an integral equation in Mathematica. It is

$$
\Psi(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right)^{\mathrm{T}} e^{i k x}+\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \hat{G}^M\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^{\prime}\right) \widetilde{V}\left(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}\right) \Psi\left(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}\right) d^2 \mathbf{r}^{\prime},
$$
where $\hat{G}^M$ is a 2x2 greens function matrix that I know analytically, $\widetilde{V}$ is some radial potential, and $\psi$ is the wave function (a vector in spin dimensions)

Are there any good techniques/references to solve such a problems that you could recommend? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT :
The definitions of the greens propagator and potential are as follows :
$$
\hat{G}^M(r,\phi)=-\frac{i k}{4}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
H_0^{(1)}(k r) & i e^{-i \phi} H_1^{(1)}(k r) \\
i e^{i \phi} H_1^{(1)}(k r) & H_0^{(1)}(k r)
\end{array}\right],
$$
where $k$ is fixed (incident wave vector with energy $\hbar v_{F}k$, $v_F$ is fermi velocity $\approx$ $c / 300$ for graphene)
$$
V(r) = V_{0}\left(1 - \left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^2\right)
$$
Thank you.

Comment: Could you show this equation with definitions for all functions involved?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have added the definitions. Thanks.

Comment: Are $H_1^{(1)},H_0^{(1)}$ known functions?

Comment: @AlexTrounev These are hankel functions of first kind

Answer (score 0):

Generally integral equations are solved as fixpoints of the nesting

```
\[Psi][r_, n_?(# > 1 &)] := 
 a[r] + int[G[r - x[n - 1]]*\[Psi][x[n - 1], n - 1], x[n - 1]]
```

The recursion result for n=3

```
\[Psi][r, 3]

a[r] + int[G[r - x[2]] (a[x[2]] + int[G[-x[1] + x[2]] \[Psi][x[1], 1], x[1]]),x[2]]
```

and so on Until[] the difference converges in Cauchy L^2-norm below a given epsilon.